# How can I disable bookmarklets from being ran?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

On my website, I want to prevent bookmarklets from being ran (either by clicking on an existing bookmark or typing the javascript in the url bar, ex **javascript:alert(1)**) I don't want any custom code to be ran on my website. There might not be a native way, but is there a "hack" that would disable execution of bookmarklets or even detecting when a bookmarklet is ran.

Answer (score 2):

The best you could do is to break references to (some) global properties, preventing the bookmarklet from being able to use them, eg:

```
window.alert = null;
```

If you put that into your code, bookmarklets will not be able to use `alert`. You can do the same sort of thing for most window properties. (To keep *your script* from breaking, save a reference to it first, eg:

```
(() => {
  const alert = window.alert;
  window.alert = null;
  // rest of your script here, referencing `alert`
})();
```

But the bookmarklet will still be able to run JS that doesn't involve such global properties. Also, if the user uses a *userscript* instead of a bookmarklet, they'll be able to save a reference to the variables before you destroy the references.

Fundamentally, it's not possible to prevent anyone determined to run their own JS on your website; it's the client's browser, they can run whatever they want on it, if they're determined enough. This isn't something that you can reliably control. Generally, the best you can do is just verify *on the server* that the inputs the user is sending are valid. Don't trust anything that comes from client-side JavaScript code.

Comment: Yup, this isn't about verifying client side code, and I'm aware there would probably never be a full-proof method for this. I just don't want people to run their own code on my site, mainly for anticheat purposes.